# JQuery: different versions clashing - is there a way I can isolate the versions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

on my site I am using a few of the newish JQuery UI controls like the datepicker and dialog.

I recently found a cool project online showing how to make the google dashboard, which is also used on the bbc.co.uk website.
This allows the user to have widgets that move around nicely when selected.

I created a test solution, it worked.

When I integrated it into my exisitng solution with currect Jquery controls and versions it causes a number of errors shown in firebug.

These are:

```
$("#menu").mouseleave is not a function
$('#menu').mouseleave(function() {
```

for this piece of code:

```
    $('#menu').mouseleave(function() {
        setSubItemVisibility();
    });
```

for the datepicker JQuery ui control:

```
$(".startdate").datepicker is not a function
$(".startdate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

for the dialog:

```
$("#inputupdatecontrol").dialog is not a function
position: 'top center'
```

These all work fine until I put in the inettuts with cookies dashobard solution in found here: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/inettuts-with-cookies/

This includes the following JQuery versions and files:

```
jquery-1.2.6.min.js
jquery-ui-personalized-1.6rc2.min.js
cookie.jquery.js
inettuts.js
```

Is there any way I can seperate the functionality that comes with these files from my existing JQuery versions?
I am currently using the latest Jquery version out and have no problems, its only when i add this functionality from the old versions that I face problems.

I am only using this old version of Jquery on one page, but ofcourse the new versions are needed to.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Okay here is the full pattern, put the following in:

```
<script src="jQuery1.3.js"></script>
<script>
    jq13 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="jQuery1.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
    jq131 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- original author's jquery version -->
<script src="jQuery1.2.3.js"></script>
```

> The variables jq13 and jq131 would
>   each be used for the version-specific
>   features you require.

Jquery in the command above returns a reference to its self essentially 'boxing' it in another variable.

So to call a function on 1.3 you would call

```
jq13('#'+ myId).bind('onclick',function(){});
```

NOTE : You must load the first version of javascript that was developed last.

Comment: thanks @Pete2k, this looks like the answer but how do i implement it? Do I use this for the latest JQuery version or the old one for the dashboard (version 1.2.6). I have used this and still get the same errors.

Comment: thanks Pete2k, It still won't work, I'm not too sure what you mean about the order of loading the files

Comment: The problem is that, the file looking for Jquery 1.2.6 cannot find it. I have replaced the $ in the file with jq126 but still get errors: like .sortable is not a function or loads of other parts.."is not a function"

Comment: My last comment means that the original version that was written must be the last one to be referenced on the page. I would start by removing all references of JQuery getting all of you calls. Make only one instance of jQuery attached to the page and then call alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);, then add the next version and call alert(jQuery+n.fn.jquery); etc until you know you are calling the correct version. Remeber to load each version of jQuery into a different variable and only call that variable not the jQuery or $. Just make sure its all seperate you cant fail that way :-), let me know

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use [jQuery.noConflict](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page).